# What are the common approaches to files structure inside source set

Tags: java, android

I'm using `gradle` for building files and it prescribes folders structure down to the level of source set, however I'm interested how to group files inside source sets, i.e. files inside `src/main/java` and `src/main/res` folders. Currently, I have all files in one folder like this:

```
ActivityMain.java
ActivityTexts.java
ActivityPodcasts.java
FragmentTexts.java
FragmentLoadedTexts.java
FragmentPodcasts.java
UtilityClass1.java
UtilityClass2.java
...
```

I'm thinking there's got to be some approach for grouping, for example:

```
Texts
|
|- ActivityTexts.java
|- FragmentTexts.java
Podcasts:
|
|- ActivityPodcasts.java
|- FragmentPodcasts.java
Utilities
|
|- UtilityClass1.java
|- UtilityClass2.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is known as a Java package and can be defined in your Java classes.

The Java tutorial has an explanation of what a package is:

> A package is a grouping of related types providing access protection
>   and name space management. Note that types refers to classes,
>   interfaces, enumerations, and annotation types. - [(source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)

To create a package, just add the following to the top of your classes:

```
package com.yourapplication.yourpackage;

//your code here
```

Alternatively, it is easily created in Android Studio by right clicking on your java folder and selecting `New > Package`

[image]

Comment: thanks, what about `/res/layout`, `/res/values/styles` folders?

Comment: Resource files within Android are not usually treated in the same way as the java source files. If you wish to group them within their folders, I would suggest doing it by name _only_ and not creating subfolders

Comment: Thanks, so I'm wondering how many files an average project has and it's probably not easy navigating among them

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to organize your source code. It's what we call packages, and two versions are widely accepted:

1. By type
2. By functionality

In your example, you have provided a grouping by type (texts, podcasts, utilities). Personally, I favour organizing things by functionality, or domain. So, I have a domain 'activity', and a domain 'fragments'. This makes it really easy to modularize your application.

Comment: thanks, what about `/res/layout`, `/res/values/styles` folders?